# How to detect new objects that were not there using OpenCV python?

Tags: python, opencv, object, detection

I want to make a drone that can detect objects from up. I found examples 
of Background Subtraction but it detects things and then considers new image as background object. I want the drone to come to it's way point and see if something new is detected. 
Drone will fly by itself and the image processing will be done using Opencv on Raspberry pi. How do I write the code in python for this? I can code in python. Please tell me what should I follow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background subtraction don't works on drones, a stabilized camera don't help. It need to search a homography matrix between frames with subpixel quality and create custom background subtraction algorithm. This work is not work Raspberry and Python.

If you know anything about objects then try to use neural networks for detection. MobileNet v3 can work on Raspberry.

For training do you can use datasets:

1. http://aiskyeye.com/
2. https://gdo152.llnl.gov/cowc/
3. http://cvgl.stanford.edu/projects/uav_data/
4. https://github.com/gjy3035/Awesome-Crowd-Counting#datasets

Comment: Actually I planned to detect intruder vehicle on hills or mountain roads. Now to train a model I need a lot of images from hill top. How can I get them? Is there any easier way to do such detection other than training? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I think that it will enough to train model with vehicle in normal scenes.

Comment: Do you have links to some existing pretrained .xml files which are free  to detect vehicle??

One problem, from hill top we cant actually see full car body for say trees. How  would you solve that? Pre trained models are trained using full body of a car, right?

Comment: The full body is optional.
The best model for this problem is RetinaNet: https://medium.com/data-from-the-trenches/object-detection-with-deep-learning-on-aerial-imagery-2465078db8a9
But for you I'm recommending the MobileNet v2. OpenCV can make inference for it.

Comment: And partial covered vehicles: https://medium.com/geoai/parking-lot-vehicle-detection-using-deep-learning-49597917bc4a

Comment: Thank you, I'm now going through your links.